# How to correct this bug of href in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, listview

I have to know how can i fill this a html

`<a href='<%# GetHRef() %>'></a>`

```
protected string GetHRef()
{
   string ret = "";
   ret = '<%# Eval("Id", "Play.aspx?lfs=Workout&Id={0}") %>'; //here is a Error
   //Cannot implicitly convert type 'char' to 'string'
   //Too many characters in character literal
   return ret;
}
```

what is wrong in code please give me solution about it 
       //Cannot implicitly convert type 'char' to 'string'
       //Too many characters in character literal
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use scriptlet to embed C# code in html and you are try to use it in c# code rather.

```
protected string GetHRef()
{
   string ret = "";
   ret = Eval("Id", "Play.aspx?lfs=Workout&Id={0}");      
   return ret;
}
```